# How do I insert values into the title of my graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a value calculated:

```
a = 32.123
```

In the title of my graph I would like to use this number.  I have tried this but it is not working:

```
title('Traffic Flow in A Day: ESTIMATED TOTAL CARS = %d',a);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
title(sprintf('Traffic Flow in A Day: ESTIMATED TOTAL CARS = %d',a));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), using the output of this and concatenating this together with a character vector.  In other words:

```
title(['Traffic Flow in A Day: ESTIMATED TOTAL CARS = ' num2str(a)]);
```

This may look more readable rather than using `sprintf`, but certainly your call!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable you can use `num2str()` to convert it to str and then you can use `strcat()` to join it with another string. E.g.:

```
Title_line= strcat('Traffic Flow in A Day: ESTIMATED TOTAL CARS = ' , num2str(a));
title(Title_line);
```

or if you don't need the string again you can do it inside the title:

```
title(strcat('Traffic Flow in A Day: ESTIMATED TOTAL CARS = ',num2str(a)));
```

The advantage is, that you can use the same string numerous times. If you define it outside of the title.